# jQuery ui autocomplete array should come form text()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

jQuery ui autocomplete array should:

**[find fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/fdyz3whd/1/)**

```
var availableTags = [
    "How are you doing?",
    "What are you doing?",
    "What did you eat today?",
    "Be Yourself",
    "Try new things"
];
```

These variables should come from `.text()` question form a tag.

```
<a class="toggle FAQCategory" href="">How are you doing?</a>
<a class="toggle FAQCategory" href="">What are you doing?</a>
<a class="toggle FAQCategory" href="">What did you eat today?</a>
<a class="toggle FAQCategory" href="">Be Yourself</a>
<a class="toggle FAQCategory" href="">Try new things</a>
```

I hope you got what I want.

I don't want to static input in jQuery ui arrays it should come dynamically is per text of question a tag.

**[find fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/fdyz3whd/1/)**

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ Refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, You can keep availableTags array. 
Do this,

```
var availableTags =[];
$(".FAQCategory").each(function(){
 availableTags.push($(this).text());
 });
```

so availableTags will iterate all anchor tags with class  FAQCategory. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since `source` requires data as an array and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array and it can be used like this

```
source: function( request, response ) {
  // .map will iterate through each .FAQCategory element and return its text content 
  // and automatically pushes into an array
  var data = $('.FAQCategory').map(function(){ return $(this).text(); }); 
  response( data );
}
```

Updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/fdyz3whd/2/**